# How to convert a string which contains date into a mysql timestamp format?

Tags: python, mysql, formatting, python-datetime, sql-timestamp

I am working in python environment. I have a date string which is like this - `26 Apr 2022 17:23:17 GMT`
I want to insert this date into mysql where the date column datatype is timestamp. How can I achieve this?

```
My variables are like this (id=1, name="Jack", date="26 Apr 2022 17:23:17 GMT")
mycurser = mydb.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO sample_table (id,name,date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
val = (id, name, date)
mycurser.execute(sql,val)
```

Here date is string and mysql datatype is timestamp.

Comment: Since it is unclear if you are asking for a solution in Python or in SQL for me, does [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/6771046) in Python answer your question?

Comment: I have updated the question, I want solution in python, so that the date I am inserting in mysql goes in timestamp format

Answer (score 2):

You could use `STR_TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('26 Apr 2022 17:23:17 GMT', '%d %b %Y %H:%i:%s');
-- 2022-04-26 17:23:17
```

Using your Python script:

```py
sql = """INSERT INTO sample_table (id, name, date)
         SELECT %s, %s, STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%d %b %Y %H:%i:%s')"""
val = (id, name, date)
mycurser.execute(sql, val)
```

Comment: If I write this in place of %s, it doesn't work

Comment: After executing the script, still not able to insert data in table, if I only insert id and name using this syntax then it works but with STR_TO_DATE it doesn't